# Three js progressive enhancement for devices

Tags: javascript, three.js

Does anyone have any advice regarding progressive enhancement for Three js projects on devices?
I have an app with lots of post-processing which is fine on modern devices but a bit slow on older/cheaper phones.  It would be nice to enable post-layers progressively for devices that can handle it.
Is there a reasonably reliable way to measure performance so as to automate this?

Comment: I have been thinking about this recently too. I was thinking to watch the fps and switch between different modes depending on fps. I haven't actually tried to implement anything yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the everyday world of real-time game development on heterogenous devices: PCs, mobiles, or cross-platform consoles...

You might consider simply keeping a list of common hardware profiles. While there are many kinds of phone there are actually very few different GPU architectures used in most all of them. This is the method that has been used by Chrome on Android, for example, to determine which devices work with WebGL and which don't.

I admit that this might seem crude, that there *ought* to be some clean way to determine which devices will perform well on your code but frankly it will be different for different devices, which is why companies like NVIDIA have test labs that evaluate products against a wide variety of hardware configurations and then they still end up generating some sort of table of performance options for that single game title, rather than building some function that can figure out performance from First Principles.

A few years ago I was scoping-out a system for a game company at which I worked that would measure a range of performance parameters for each individual user and attempt, via regression ("machine learning") to determine the best performance profile for THAT user on THEIR machine because even with a narrow range of hardware choices you still can never tell just how much other stuff is going on on the player's computer. Are they running youtube and teamspeak and who knows what else in the background? Hard to predict the at-home situation, even in a large testing lab. So an adaptive approach might be the best, but even then it is very numerically-intensive and probably not a good fit (today) for javascript-based web apps using THREE.js. So if you want to attack this problem, choose your strategies (drop compositing layers? Opt for simpler geometry? Fewer or simpler shaders? Depends on your app!), try them yourself (experience will trump speculation every time!) , and then start deploying to the public. If your users permit it, ask them to store a cookie. But expect a long iterative process if you really want it to work.